# Backbone Marionette CompositeView repeated messed up tables inside the rows

Tags: templates, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, icanhaz.js

I think I'm clearly doing something wrong. 
I [replaced the underscore template with ICanHaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386893/backbone-marionette-and-icanhaz-mustache-templates-configuration), so now I don't know if the issue is coming from that or for another mistake in the CompositeView.
Anyway I feel I'm a little lost between the Marionette view types and regions.
Here's my code:

```
//ItemView
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','iCanHaz','models/Job','text!templates/JobItemView.tpl','marionette'], 
    function( $, _, Backbone, ich, Job, jobTemplate, Marionette) { 
        var JobView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            tagName: 'tr',
            template: jobTemplate,
        });
        return JobView;
});

// CompositeView  
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone','collections/JobList','views/JobItemView','marionette','text!templates/JobListView.tpl'], 
    function( $, _, Backbone, JobCollection, JobView, Marionette, JobListTpl ) { /*function for instantiating the module or object*/
        var JobListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
            itemView: JobView,
            template: JobListTpl,
            itemViewContainer: "tbody",
        });
        return JobListView;
});



// Item Template (jobTemplate)
<td>
    <a href="{{ url }}" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
        {{ title }}
    </a>
</td>
<td>{{ status }}</td>
<td>{{ created_at }}</td>

// Composite Template (JobListTpl)
<table class="table table-striped" id="jobs-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>created</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                Stuff in here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>


//Main HTML page
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="jobPanel">
        //stuff in here        
    </div>
//other stuff in here

//app.js
define(['backbone','marionette','iCanHaz','collections/JobList','views/JobListView'],
  function(Backbone, marionette, ich, JobList, JobListView){

    var app = new marionette.Application(),
    jobList = new JobList();

    app.addRegions({
        main   : '#content',
        jobsPanel: "#jobPanel"
    });

    app.addInitializer(function(){
        //For using Marionette with ICH
        Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data){
            if (_.isUndefined(ich[templateName])){ 
                  var templateName;
                  ich.addTemplate(templateName, template);
            };
            return ich[templateName](data); 
        }

        var viewOptions = {
            collection : jobList
        };

        app.jobsPanel.show(new JobListView(viewOptions)); 
        jobList.fetch({validate:true});
    });
    return app;

  }
);


//main.js for RequireJS config
    require.config({
        shim: {
            underscore: {
                exports: '_'
            },
            backbone: {
                deps: [
                    'underscore',
                    'jquery'
                ],
                exports: 'Backbone'
            },
            backboneLocalstorage: {
                deps: ['backbone'],
                exports: 'Store'
            },
            marionette : {
                exports : 'Backbone.Marionette',
                deps : ['backbone']
            },
            iCanHaz:{
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: 'ich'
            }
        },
        optimize: "none", 
        paths: {
            jquery: "require-jquery",
            underscore: '../lib/backbone/underscore-min',
            backbone: '../lib/backbone/backbone',
            marionette : '../lib/backbone/backbone.marionette.min',
            iCanHaz: '../lib/backbone/ICanHaz_ReqJS_Compatible',
            backboneLocalstorage: '../lib/backbone/extras/backbone.localStorage',
            text: '../lib/require/text',
        }

    });

    require(['app','backbone'],function(app,Backbone){
      app.start();
    });
```

This is supposed to create a plain table with 3 rows, but it actually creates 3 nested tables. This is the (pretty) ugly outcome: [image]
The 3 records are retrieved but not showed. So now I don't know which part I am messing up.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the templating system that I'm using (ICanHaz.js) works pretty well for simple cases. Never tried for CompositeView tough.

Comment: This sounds like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541491/weird-behavior-of-marionettejs-compositeview ... are you sure you're code is defining the JobView before the JobListView tries to use it? If so, can you build a JSFiddle or JSBin to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm using RequireJS + AMD and I'm declaring the ItemView in the "define" statement at the top of the page. I doubt the problem comes from there, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: can you update the code in the post, to show the entire module definition? it might help if we see that, so we can see how your modules are set up

Comment: @DerickBailey done. I've also added the RequireJS config at the end of the code.

Comment: my limited knowledge of requirejs says this looks fine... in the first line of your "CompositeView" module, add this: `console.log(JobView)` and see what that produces. I'm betting it outputs `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you @DerickBailey but it actually prints this: `function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }` so it is not `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe you are rendering you composite view before you actually get your collection?

Can you try this in your app.js:

`jobList.fetch({success:function(){
    app.jobsPanel.show(new JobListView({ collection: jobList })); 
}});`

Comment: @Ingro I've tried it and I obtain the exact same (wrong) result.
At this point can it be a sort of "conflict" with ICanHaz.js ?

Comment: Well I don't think, but you can try with plain underscore template and do a fast check of that.

Comment: Well, yes that was the problem! With pure underscore template I don't have this issue. But it's quite weird because ICanHaz.js did work with plain Backbone Views. So I'm guessing it's a compatibility problem with Marionette's `CompositeView`? See the code above to understand how I manage to let IcanHaz.js work with Backbone re-defying the  `Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render` method.

Comment: @Leonardo can you post your results in an answer? I'm having a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640168/integrating-icanhaz-and-marionette